# Do you say “me and my brother’s room” or “my and my brother’s room”?

Tags: possessives, possessive-pronouns, compound-subjects

I’m not sure which of the two is correct: “Me and Tessa’s Books” or  “My and Tessa’s books”? Couldn’t find an answer in grammar books.

Comment: You should avoid the use of the possessive phrase. Some people called it grammar black hole. See this https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/proper-possessives-bobs-and-marys-dog-bob-and-marys-dogs-etc.1346384/

Comment: The question and the title  are  different .

Comment: My brother's room and mine [but that means you are both in the same room] versus My brother's room and my room. Same with Tessa.

Answer (score 1):

It's considered polite, and it's more commonly used in writing, to leave the **first personal pronoun(s)**, such as *I*, and the possessive pronoun; *mine*, at the end.

For example,

> *My husband and **I***.

NOT

> *I and my husband.*

Which is perfectly grammatical but no one says it.

Therefore, in the OP's situation it is preferable to say

> Tessa's books and **mine**.
>   My brother's room and **mine**

OR

> My books and Tessa's.
>   **Our** room (if you and a sibling share the same room)

Answer (score 0):

The title and the question are different. I am answering the question.

It should be:

> **My books and Tessa's** (books)

or you may say:

> **Tessa's books and mine**.

because**me** is  the objective case of I.
 here we are talking about the possession of books.

So we have to use the possessive case of I- my or mine.