# The purpose of David and mine is to confuse you

Tags: prepositions, pronouns

The purpose of  professor David and mine is to confuse you with questions on English grammar.

Is the question correct. Since the question begins with genetive case, I think the correct pronoun is mine. some are saying that the pronoun I is correct and some others opt for me also. please find out any other mistakes regarding prepositions or others in the sentence.

Comment: You've used the singular verb form ***is***, which implies ***there is only one purpose***. So the subject of that singular verb should be referenced as *the purpose of David **and me***. It's an awkward choice of nouns though, so it might help to consider, compare, and contrast *The child of David and MINE **are** 5 years old* (both me and David have *different* 5-year-old children), and *The child of David and ME **is** 5 years old* (David and I are the parents of *the same* 5-year-old child).

Comment: @ Fumble Fingers. What do you think is the correct pronoun in the  sentence since the purpose of  David and mine is the same. I think mine is correct.

Comment: It's a bit pointless talking about "correct" forms here, when the whole construction is so "ugly" no competent native speaker would wish to use it anyway. I might switch to ***Mine and David's** purpose is blah blah*.

Comment: That is equal to The purpose of David and mine. It is just to create confusion. But there must be logic. In grammar exercises many akward sentences are given for testing. What native speakers use is not always tested in grammatical exercises.. Can we begin a sentence with first person?

Comment: Whenever a voice is raised it is supressed by going in for  a negative marking.. The purpose of a group  is to answer a question but not to suprress the poster.It is not a democratic process. I hope some member will answer this question..English is not spoken or written all over the same way. What is idiomatic and what is awkward or ugly is difficult to define. A crow likes its smaller one though it is ugly. There is no definition for ugliness or beauty. It is mere personal perceotion and bias and illusion

Comment: Well, you could look at [My father and my birthday/My father's birthday and mine/My father's and my birthday…something else?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/153696/) Also [Do you say “me and my brother’s room” or “ my and my brother’s room”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/226385/) and [“My and her” or “mine and her”.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/234530/) But I think you should forget about the concept of "syntactically correct" here. English simply doesn't have elegant ways to deal with "compound possessives", so it's best to rephrase and avoid them completely.

Comment: You can certainly start a sentence "My purpose, and David's, is to...". That doesn't sound too awkward. You can also say "David's purpose, and mine, is to...". Even if you remove "mine" entirely, "The purpose of David is to..." is not idiomatic. Expressing it as "the purpose of David" makes David sound like the name of a robot or a computer program.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I think your comment would do as an answer.

Comment: @ well. The question was given  in some other group. The actual question was THE PURPOSE OF  PROFESSOR  DAVID AND      ---------------   IS TO CONFUSE YOU WITH QUESTIONS ON ENGLISH GRAMMAR.

Comment: @ well. The question was given  in some other group. The actual question was THE PURPOSE OF  PROFESSOR  DAVID AND      ---------------   IS TO CONFUSE YOU WITH QUESTIONS ON ENGLISH GRAMMAR.  THE exercise is given simply to test the lerners knowledge of choosing the pronouns in the correct form.  All of your comments have helped to make the confusion confounded. There must be one pronou n out of the three correct.  some of the professors I know say that my sentence is formal and grammatically correct.  The professor says it is not standard English to say mine and David's purpose  is to confuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English doesn't really have a "case" system.  There are remnants of the Anglo-Saxon case system present in the pronouns (mine) and the possessive 's. But we can't really talk about a noun being in genetive (or accusative or ablative etc.) case.

With a single word it is correct to say

> John's idea
>
> An idea of John
>
> An idea of John's  (some people don't like this pattern)
>
> My idea
>
> An idea of mine

Whereas "An idea of I" is not correct

That is a bit illogical, because there is no logical reason why the last must use "mine". It's  illogical that there should be different words "my" and "mine" (they are both "genetive")

If we attempt to apply logic to this, then

> The purpose of David and mine

Is correct.  And most people would agree.

But.  In many expressions where a pronoun is used with "and", it is common to use that pronoun in its object form (reason, the whole expression is genetive, but not the individual words). So it is very common (and correct in some contexts) to say "Sarah and me are going shopping". It is also common to use "Sarah and I", even in cases where logically "me" would be better: "He gave them to Sarah and I".

If we apply the rule "use 'me' with 'and'" we get an acceptable sentence

> The purpose of David and me is to confuse you.

Some might hypercorrect this to

> The purpose of David and I is to confuse you.

In speech, I'd probably prefer "and me". If I were writing, I would avoid this by rephrasing

> Professor David and I are the tutors on this course.  Our purpose is to confuse you with questions of English grammar.

That's better.  It has proper "end weight", it uses pronouns clearly and correctly. It has a nice simple and easily parsed structure. Sometimes in grammar, you have to cut the Gordian knot and rephase.

Comment: @ Janes K. This is the most comprehensive answer and it clarifies my doubt better than I expected. Eventhough I was downvoted for my question, I feel happy that you answred the question with logic and your expertise in English.. Your answers are very clear and analytical.There is no use calling a post ugly or awkward but to discuss the pros and cons is what a good linguist does and should do.None of the comments above have clarified my doubt or those who have been grappling with this question because some of the professors I know voted for The purpose of professor David and mine is to confuse